# Wordpress display widget only on single.php

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have this widget that I would like to display EXCLUSIVELY on single.php - How can I do this?

**Additional info**: Wordpress version *4.1*
**Theme**: *Twentytwelve*

Comment: The fast  way: edit single.php and insert your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install "widget logic" plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

now you'll be able to insert conditional tags 
in your case : is_single();
You can find more detailed instruction in the plugin's link